# MySQL Select from 1 Table, Insert into Another using Where across different databases

Tags: mysql

I have a select shown below that brings back the correct count per "sender_userid".

I want to insert this into a table in another database where there is a matching column "userid".

I'm not sure how to get the WHERE clause to work when used across database.

I've tried database.table.column but this appears wrong.

Is this possible? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` statements must come before `ORDER BY` and  `GROUP BY` statements. Also you should use the `ON` operator. Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO dating_users.statistics (messages_sent)
 SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM dating_messages.messages M
 JOIN dating_users.statistics S
 ON (S.userid = M.sender_userid) 
 GROUP BY sender_userid ORDER BY sender_userid ASC;
```

Edit: sorry I didn't realize that you were missing your actual JOIN statement. Just because you are INSERTing into a table doesn't make any data accessible from that table. You still need to JOIN to it.